# Which graphs are dualizable?

Tags: category-theory

First let me make some definitions. Let $O$ be a set. An $O$-graph is a set $\Gamma$ together with two functions $s,t : \Gamma \to O$. The interpretation is: $O$ = set of vertices, $\Gamma$ = set of edges, $s = $ source, $t$ = target. The category of $O$-graphs is monoidal: The unit is $O$ with $s=t=\mathrm{id}$ and the tensor product of $(\Gamma,s,t)$ and $(\Gamma',s',t')$ is $(\Gamma \times_{t,s'} \Gamma',s \circ \mathrm{pr}_1,t' \circ \mathrm{pr}_2)$. The edges are thus pairs of edges $(f,g)$ where $f$ is an edge in $\Gamma$, and $g$ is an edge in $\Gamma'$, and $f$ ends where $g$ starts.

**Question.** What are the left/right dualizable objects in the monoidal category of $O$-graphs?

For example, the invertible objects are precisely the disjoint unions of cycles which cover $O$, thus they correspond 1:1 to permutations of $O$. (In particular, the group of permutations of $O$ has a natural categorification to a $2$-group.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category of $O$-graphs is simply the endomorphism category of $O$ in the bicategory of spans in $\mathbf{Set}$, so one can more generally ask about the spans (in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with pullbacks) that have left or right adjoints. We have the following folklore result:

> Let $X \leftarrow F \rightarrow Y$ be a span. Then $F$ has a right adjoint if and only if the "source" map $X \leftarrow F$ is an isomorphism.

See e.g. Proposition 2 in [Carboni, Kasangian and Street, [*Bicategories of spans and relations*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049%2884%2990061-6)]. Since the bicategory of spans is isomorphic to its opposite, we may deduce that a span $Y \leftarrow G \rightarrow X$ has a left adjoint if and only if the "target" map $G \to X$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. I also wondered if there is any literature about this. Sure, spans! I kind of like the way how "circular" category theory is: "Definition": A category is a monoid object in the monoidal endomorphism category of an object of the category spans. ;)

Comment: Indeed. This generalises to $\mathcal{V}$-categories as well. But there is a small problem with this definition in that the natural notion of morphism (if I recall correctly) corresponds to _profunctors_ and not functors.